Is it possible to set the state of a Fragment to stopped without destroying the view using FragmentManager?
For some reason, I would like to just move the state of a fragment to stopped after hiding it, but not to destroy it (or detach from window)
transaction.setMaxLifecycle(it, Lifecycle.State.STARTED) only invokes onPause, but transaction.setMaxLifecycle(it, Lifecycle.State.CREATED) also calls onDestroyView, which is too much.
